# Python Pandas: How to get first index where next 100 values of specific columns are 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a Pandas dataframe and want to delete all data rows after a column has the value 0 for at least 100 consecutive times. It is possible, that afterward it is not 0 anymore at some point but that should not matter.

Does anybody know how to code that? Thank you already!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).